# Excel VBA insert a hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have been trying to get a macro insert a dynamic hyperlink for a couple hours now and cannot seem to get the syntax correct.

I need to make my macro insert a hyperlink into `rLinkCell` that points to `rTargetCell` in `shTargetSheet`, use the label or display text `stLinkName` and have the Screen tip `stTip`.

I have gotten this far:

```
shCurSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rLinkCell, _
           Address:="", _
           SubAddress:=shTargetSheet.Name & "!" & rTargetCell.Address, _
           ScreenTip:=stTip, _
           TextToDisplay:=stLinkName
```

It makes the link perfectly and all the displays are fine, however when I click it I get an error saying `Refrence is not valid`.

I am certain it is something simple, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the rest of your code, or at least a minimum example (where you declare and assign your variables) so that we can attempt to resolve the problem. I *think* you need to be doing this to the Address property, not the SubAddress property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is create a hyperlink on a sheet, you can just use the =HYPERLINK() function.

I've just create an example workbook, here's the formula solution:
https://spreadgit.com/bjoern/hyperlink-example.xlsb/sheets/Sheet1

and here's the VBA solution:
https://spreadgit.com/bjoern/hyperlink-example.xlsb/modules/Module1